# Split string on multiple delimiters but not on white space alone

Tags: python, regex

I'm doing

```
delimiters = [r'\r\n', r'\.\.\.', r'\W']
pattern = regex.compile(r'(' + r'|'.join(delimiters) + r')', flags=regex.V1)
pattern.split(s)
```

to split `s` on multiple delimiters (using parentheses to retain delimiters in the output).

How can I prevent splitting on white space when it occurs alone? For example,

```
'abc, def , geh,, , ijk      lmn \n opq'
```

should give

```
`['abc', ', ', 'def', ' , ', 'geh', ',, , ', 'ijk      lmn', ' \n ', 'opq']
```

That is, when white space occurs together with another delimiter, the split should be performed but not when it there is only white space between the tokens. By white space I really only mean white space ' ', not any other tokens such as line break.s

(These are actually two questions, as right now I'm getting `['abc', ',', '', ' ', 'def', ' ', 'geh']`, that is, multiple delimiters come out separately, while I would like them to come out aggregated.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `regex` module you could use:

```
import regex
arr = ['abc,, def', 'abc, def geh', 'abc  def', 'abc, def , geh,, , ijk      lmn \n opq']
res = [regex.split(r'\b(?=\W)(?! +\b)|(?<=\b\W*[^\w ]+\W*\b)',x) for x in arr]
print(res)
```

Prints:

```
[['abc', ',, ', 'def'], ['abc', ', ', 'def geh'], ['abc  def'], ['abc', ', ', 'def', ' , ', 'geh', ',, , ', 'ijk      lmn', ' \n ', 'opq']]
```

---

The pattern matches:

- `\b` - Word boundary.
- `(?=\W)` - A positive lookahead of a non-word character.
- `(?!\s\b)` - Negative lookahead for a space character and a word boundary.
- `|` - Or
- `(?<=\b\W*[^\w\s]+\W*\b)` - A positive lookbehind for a word-boundary, zero or more non-word characters, at least one character other than wordcharacter or whitespace character and followed by (greedy) non-word characters if possible and a word-boundary.

Comment: I hope I will once arrive at this level of `RegEx` wizardry :) Could you maybe explain a little bit how it works for mere mortals to learn? :)

Comment: The way I understand it, it probably only works for comma. Is it possible to extend it to work with any character in `\W`?

Comment: I'm no wizard by any mean, simply trying my best. But I'll update with some explaination.

Comment: I've tried `r'(?=[\W--\s]\s+)|(?<=[\W--\s]\s+)'` and it seems to work, but I noticed one problem. `'abc,, def'` gives `['abc,', ', ', 'def']`. That is, the first comma is not considered as delimiter.

Comment: With your last edit, it would still not combine all the delimiters in the output. I could fix this with post processing though. Just wondering if that can already be part of the regex.

Comment: What exactly did you have in mind for output considering 'abc,, def'? @Konstantin. Or what other edge-case is not working? Let us know.

Comment: All delimiters in `\W` should be combined together in the output.

Comment: @Konstantin, it gets a bit vague to be honest. I've updated the pattern. Please give it a shot and report back.

Comment: Sorry. The last one is really close, it just would still split on multiple white spaces. That is `'abc  def'` gets split if there is more than one white space in it.

Comment: @Konstantin, I believe that is fixed now too.

Comment: Man, I think you did it!!

Comment: Oh god, I still found an edge case that doesn't work. When I wrote white space I really only meant white space, not line breaks :( The last version would not split on line breaks. I'll edit the question in a sec.

Comment: @Konstantin, just change `\s` to ` ` (an actual space) in the pattern.

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```
import re
delimiters = [r'\r\n', r'\.\.\.', r'[^\w\s]']
d = r"|".join(delimiters)
pattern = re.compile(rf'((?:\s*(?:{d}))+\s*)')
s = 'abc, def , geh,, , ijk      lmn'
print( pattern.split(s) )
# => ['abc', ', ', 'def', ' , ', 'geh', ',, , ', 'ijk      lmn']
```

See the [Python demo](https://tio.run/##VY7RCsIgFIbvfYrDulBreNNdED3IXLA211zTiQoR1bOvow0ij@h/9PsPv3vEYbb7ZdHGzT6CV6RTkzY6Kh/gCJWn0ktLS0AhUmVZneVdhprWpEPIF69CjLO27OflxDURhU3/SrSzcXpSzPeUsdNBhi2ez@7N@Q41p5xsKtpcWpy@7k716YJvd1VDfi/XXo83yGsyFlOkqMleAtoQQTyjfxhxXtvIYA0mgpt0ZIEDX5YP).

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/G6W9im/1) meaning

- `(?:\s*(?:\r\n|\.\.\.|[^\w\s]))+` - one or more repetitions of:

  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `(?:\r\n|\.\.\.|[^\w\s])` - one of your delimiter patterns
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces

Note `\W` is replaced with `[^\w\s]` to match any punctuation (any non-word char but whitespace chars).

Comment: This one is really close. Only it will still consider multiple white spaces as a delimiter.

Comment: With the last edit, `'abc , geh'` gives `['abc ', ', ', 'geh']`. That is, the first white space is not recognized as delimiter.

Comment: @Konstantin Ok, temporarily rolled back to Version 1. Please check  [this Python demo](https://tio.run/##RY1BDsIgEEX3nGLSDVAbNu5MjAcpNamFthgKZCBRo54dwZiY2bzM//MmPNLq3T5nswWPCVAv@k6UtmYzSWOEI/RIJUpHOygg6nyxP8ubjAMdiColbF6NuHrj2P@WkzCmAq7m1SsmvwVjNcOZMhnbp3qz00HGXQHelgWnnNSXdLxMHSg9w6JXSgIalxj8bCIGaxKLHHjOHw)

Comment: @Konstantin You may use `re` with my solution

Comment: Very nice @WiktorStribiżew